# XML attributes query in Qexo.

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I've the following XML, I used Xquerry to query some results using Qexo. How to query only the attributes like affiliation? Like if i want to query all affiliations of each author?

I could do the simpler ones, but this is very tricky and din't get any online reference......

```
    <conference>
<paper>
<conferencename>VLDB</conferencename>
<year>2006</year>
<author affiliation="ASU"> K. Selçuk Candan</author>
    <author affiliation="NEC America"> Wang-Pin Hsiung</author>
    <author affiliation="Turn"> Songting Chen</author>
    <author affiliation="NEC America"> Jun'ichi Tatemura</author>
    <author affiliation="UCSB">Divyakant Agarwal</author> 
<Article>AFilter: Adaptable XML Filtering with Prefix-Caching and Suffix-Clustering. 559-570
Electronic Edition (link) BibTeX </Article>
<place>Seoul, Korea</place>
</paper>
</conference>
```

Just to return all values , this is the Xquery used.

```
for $x in doc("vldb.xml")/conference/paper
where $x/conferencename = "VLDB"
order by $x/Author
return
<x>
{ $x/Author, $x/Article, $x/conferencename, $x/year}
</x>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to specify what is the wanted output** ... ?

**Try something like this**:

```
for $x in /conference/paper 
  where $x/conferencename = "VLDB" 
  order by $x/Author 

    return
      <x  affiliation = "{$x/author/@affiliation}"> 
         {$x/author, $x/Article, $x/conferencename, $x/year}
      </x>
```